# Does Postgres Automatically Clean Up Stuck Queries?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Take the following block from my postgres instance:

```
postgres=> SELECT pid, query_start from pg_stat_activity ORDER BY pid;
  pid  |          query_start          
-------+-------------------------------
   374 | 
   375 | 
   376 | 
   377 | 
   380 | 
  1185 | 2023-03-07 00:06:49.97674+00
  1222 | 2023-03-07 00:06:56.795915+00
  3449 | 2023-03-06 21:57:26.409735+00
  3518 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.661874+00
 17950 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.590964+00
 17951 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.659922+00
 17952 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.659469+00
 17953 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.656676+00
 17954 | 2023-03-07 00:06:57.647601+00
(14 rows)
```

Clearly the query with PID 3449 is stuck, it has been hanging for over two hours. I don't want to have to clean stuck queries up manually with `pg_backend_terminate(pid)`.

Does Postgres automatically clean up stuck queries? If so, when? Can I configure Postgres to automatically terminate a PID after a certain interval length?

Comment: Why is it taking so long? Is some other pid blocking it?

Comment: So what is the `state` of those queries?

Comment: "slow" and "stuck" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, PostgreSQL **does not** automatically terminate stuck queries. It relies on the administrator to manually intervene and terminate them using `pg_terminate_backend()` or `pg_cancel_backend()`.

However, PostgreSQL does provide a way to set a timeout for queries using the `statement_timeout` parameter. When set, if a query runs longer than the specified timeout, PostgreSQL will automatically terminate the query and release its resources.

You can set this parameter either on the session level or globally. For example, to set the timeout to 1 hour globally, you can add the following line to your `postgresql.conf` file:

```
statement_timeout = 3600000
```

> Setting statement_timeout in `postgresql.conf` is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.

Alternatively, you can set the timeout on a per-session basis by running the following SQL command:

```sql
SET statement_timeout = '1h';
```

Note that setting the timeout too low can result in legitimate queries being terminated prematurely. You should set it to a value that is suitable to your use case.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html
- https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/statement_timeout/