# Why is AWS Postgres not cleaning up my stuck transactions?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Following up on my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/324450/does-postgres-automatically-clean-up-stuck-queries), I have been trying to make Postgres automatically clean up stuck queries. I am running Postgres 11 on AWS RDS.

I set the `statement_timeout` to 1800000 ms in AWS RDS parameter groups, and applied it to my database:
[image]

Then I ensured it had applied correctly:
[image]

However, I clearly still have an active transaction that's been stuck for ~10 hours:
[image]

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses the setting that was active when the query started. You'll have to cancel that statement yourself, but it will work as intended for future statements.

Comment: This can't be it, because the problem is still happening. I have another one just from today. Surely the setting should be applying to this query? https://imgur.com/5iCdnmQ

Comment: Well, that's how it works in PostgreSQL. I can't speak about modifications made by Amazon.